How to initialize db connection in FastAPI with lifespan events?
I would like to initialize a DB connection for my FastAPI application and tried to follow the tutorial for Lifespan Events.
I set up a lifecycle function and plugged it into my app and within the function, the variable is initialized but after the start up, the variable remains None.
db_session = None


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    db_session = DBConnection("file.db")
    if db_session.get_db_connection() is None:
        raise InitializationError("Could not get access database file.")
    print(db_session.get_test_value()) # Prints out a valid value
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
print(db_session) # Prints None

Versions

Python 3.9
FastAPI 0.114.2
Pydantic 2.9.1
uvicorn 0.30.6

What I tried
I initialized the value with [] instead of None.
I initialized the value with {} instead of None (like in the tutorial).
I plugged the db session into `db_session["db"] instead of assigning it directly, the map remains empty.
I initialized the value in lifespan with a string, just to test.
I declared the variable db_session as global in the lifespan function before assigning it the value.
All tests lead to the same result, that the value is as initialized outside of the lifespanfunction (None or [] or {}).
The error persists during the handling of the requests.

Edit: The real answer is the @Dunes comment

There is no guarantee that the lifespan function is executed before FastAPI(lifespan=...) returns. Instead, it guarantees the lifespan func will have run before your app starts servicing requests.

In lifespan() you are declaring new a local variable with the same name. If you want to overwrite global variable, you need to add global declaration:
db_session = None

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app):
    global db_session
    db_session = DBConnection("file.db")
    ...

Alternatively, it may be stored in app state object:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app):
    app.state["db"] = DBConnection("file.db")
    ...

Example
# example.py

from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app):
    app.state.connection = {'status': 'ok'}
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return app.state.connection


Run fastapi dev example.py
Open http://127.0.0.1:8000


Thanks. As I wrote in the update, I tested declaring it as global but to the same effect. It also is not done in the tutorial

@guerda I usually store database object in app.state: https://www.starlette.io/applications/#storing-state-on-the-app-instance

@guerda There is no guarantee that the lifespan function is executed before FastAPI(lifespan=...) returns. Instead, it guarantees the lifespan func will have run before your app starts servicing requests.

That's a good point, @Dunes . The error persists though during the handling the first http requests.

Did you follow the advice of using global db_session or using app.state as well? Also, it looks like you are using sqlite3, so you will also have to mark your API methods as async. Otherwise they get run in separate threads, and sqlite3 throws an exception when you try to use the connection.

As I wrote, I tested the global definition without effect. I also tested assigning just a simple string, but also that is not available in the http requests. The API is async.

What irks me is that I'm literally copying the tutorial and it doesn't work that way.

I found a workaround by using a dependency instead of the async context manager.

@guerda could you please try Example above. I tested it and it works.
